# Sphere and Cube of same mass requires different force to lift

Tags: forces, mass

I am new to Game development, I was just exploring Unity3d. I inserted two game objects first, a `sphere` and a `cube` , of same mass (1 ).

On pressing the up arrow key, I'm adding a positive vertical force.(down arroy key for negative vertical force).

```
 ^         ^
 |         |
 |         |
sphere   cube
```

Sphere within an instant moves up, but cube required more force to move. When I increased the mass of sphere to 10. They started moving up and down simultaneously. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics

Comment: To a first approximation the force needed to support an object depends only on its mass and not its shape. There is a small change to this force due to the buoyant force from the air around it that depends on the volume of the object (which is related to the shape). It seems likely this is a quirk of the software.

Comment: [gamedev.se] might be better suited for this question